# U-SQL cursor in Azure Data Lake

Tags: loops, azure, cursor, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I need to process data in Azure Data Lake.
My flow is as follows:

1. I would like to select from the database list of IDs for next processing. This I have done.
2. I need to iterate through IDs (from the first step) and I need to successively export data into separated files (partitioned by ID)

The problem is following [statemanet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621314.aspx):

> U-SQL’s procedures do not provide any imperative code-flow constructs
>   such as a for or while loops.

Any idea how to process data in similar way as with cursor?

I didn't find any documentation regarding to the cursors in U-SQL.

Thank you!

Comment: This is the same as your other question. I repeat USQL isn't for iterating.

Comment: Is not the same, this question is related to the cursor or loops and similar cases (my other question is related to the file partitioning). This was a reason why I splitted the questions, because I would like to know whether iterative approach is possible or not and in my other question I would like to know how to partition file by key value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no cursors in U-SQL, because of the statement you reference above.

*U-SQL does not provide any imperative code-flow constructs* because it impedes the optimizer's ability to globally optimize your script.

You should think of approaching your problem declaratively. For example, if you have a list of IDs (either in a table or SqlArray or even a file), use a declarative join. For example, you want to add 42 to every value where the key is in a list of existing keys:

```
// Two options for providing the "looping data"
// Option 1: Array Variable
DECLARE @keys_var = new SqlArray<string>{"k1", "k2", "k3"};

// Option 2: Rowset (eg from an EXTRACT from file, a table or other place)
@keys = SELECT * FROM (VALUES("k1"), ("k2"), ("k3")) AS T(key);

// This is the data you want to iterate over to add 42 to the value column for every matching key
@inputdata = SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, "k1"), (2, "k1"), (3, "k2"), (6, "k5")) AS T(value, key);

//Option 1:
@res = SELECT value+42 AS newval, key FROM @inputdata WHERE @keys_var.Contains(key);

OUTPUT @res TO "/output/opt1.csv" USING Outputters.Csv();

//Option 2:
@res = SELECT value+42 AS newval, i.key 
    FROM @inputdata AS i INNER JOIN @keys AS k 
         ON i.key == k.key;

OUTPUT @res TO "/output/opt2.csv" USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Now in your case, you want to have data-driven output file sets. This feature is currently being worked on (it is one of our [top asks](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/10550388-support-dynamic-output-file-names-in-adla)). Until then you would have to write a script to generate the script (I will provide an example on your other question).

Comment: Thank you Michael. Could you please describe what you meant with declarative join?
Do you have any example or tutorial?

Comment: Updated above. Note that this does not work for `OUTPUT` but for general processing.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want iterative behaviour you need to call the USQL from PowerShell.

For example:

```
ForEach ($Date in $Dates)
    {
    $USQLProcCall = '[dbo].[usp_OutputDailyAvgSpeed]("' + $Date + '");'
    $JobName = 'Output daily avg dataset for ' + $Date

    Write-Host $USQLProcCall

    $job = Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob `
        -Name $JobName `
        -AccountName $DLAnalyticsName `
        –Script $USQLProcCall `
        -DegreeOfParallelism $DLAnalyticsDoP

    Write-Host "Job submitted for " $Date
    }
```

Source: https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2017/05/recursive-u-sql-with-powershell-u-sql-looping/

Comment: Thank you Paul. I solved it partially via loops in Powershell work flow running u-sql. Now I try your suggestions. Thanks a lot!